# Ubuntu hibernate and suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Why hibernate doesn't work on my laptop but works correctly when I use windows?
By typing `sudo pm-hibernate` system goes to hibernate but starts with error.

---

My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04
RAM:6 GB
swap partition:7 GB
lenovo z50-70

I have a problem in suspend too. when system goes to suspend automatically, a blank screen comes up. I'm newly to Linux.
Please help.

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough information in your question to help.

You mention that hibernate "starts" with an error message, but you don't mention what the error was.

Since you're running Ubuntu, you might want to try doing some initial troubleshooting and then report back here what you've discovered.

To get you started, try this site: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate

Additionally, since Ubuntu 16.04 uses [systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/systemd.1.html), you may want to focus your debugging efforts on the [native systemd services for suspend and hibernate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/hibernate.8.html).

Best of luck!